# Is it possible to build AOSP lollipop using java 1.8?

Tags: android, java-8, android-source

I have a device based on android lollipop and Im trying to bulild AOSP-android lollipop(22) with java 1.8.So why java 1.8 ? Because i want to use some libraries compiled in java 1.8.I have installed java 1.8 in my ubuntu machine and tried to build AOSP now im getting the following exception

Is it actually possible to build AOSP lollipop using java 1.8 ?

```
 symbol:   class SSLClientSessionCache
  location: class SSLSessionCache
frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/backup/LocalTransport.java:36: error: package com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders does not exist
import com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
                                                 ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:19: error: package com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509 does not exist
import com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator;
                                        ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:21: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:22: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngine;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java:19: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:19: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:19: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngine;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:20: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKeyHolder;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:23: error: package com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem does not exist
import com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
                                               ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:24: error: package com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem does not exist
import com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;
                                               ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:25: error: package com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem does not exist
import com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;
                                               ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:43: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngine;
                                ^
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:44: error: package com.android.org.conscrypt does not exist
import com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustedCertificateStore;
                                ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java:989: error: cannot find symbol
            long openSslSocketCount = Debug.countInstancesOfClass(OpenSSLSocketImpl.class);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class ActivityThread.ApplicationThread
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java:5236: error: cannot find symbol
        TrustedCertificateStore.setDefaultUserDirectory(configDir);
        ^
  symbol:   variable TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class ActivityThread
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java:1869: error: cannot find symbol
                final TrustedCertificateStore certStore = new TrustedCertificateStore();
                      ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class DevicePolicyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java:1869: error: cannot find symbol
                final TrustedCertificateStore certStore = new TrustedCertificateStore();
                                                              ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class DevicePolicyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java:1892: error: cannot find symbol
            for (String alias : new TrustedCertificateStore().userAliases()) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class DevicePolicyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java:1956: error: cannot find symbol
        return new TrustedCertificateStore().getCertificateAlias(cert);
                   ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class DevicePolicyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Network.java:224: error: cannot find symbol
                mHostResolver = new HostResolver() {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class HostResolver
  location: class Network
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Network.java:232: error: cannot find symbol
                mConnectionPool = new ConnectionPool(httpMaxConnections,
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ConnectionPool
  location: class Network
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Network.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
        OkHttpClient client;
        ^
  symbol:   class OkHttpClient
  location: class Network
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Network.java:285: error: cannot find symbol
            client = HttpHandler.createHttpOkHttpClient(proxy);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable HttpHandler
  location: class Network
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Network.java:287: error: cannot find symbol
            client = HttpsHandler.createHttpsOkHttpClient(proxy);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable HttpsHandler
  location: class Network
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/CertificateChainValidator.java:231: error: cannot find symbol
            X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = SSLParametersImpl.getDefaultX509TrustManager();
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable SSLParametersImpl
  location: class CertificateChainValidator
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/CertificateChainValidator.java:232: error: cannot find symbol
            if (x509TrustManager instanceof TrustManagerImpl) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class TrustManagerImpl
  location: class CertificateChainValidator
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/CertificateChainValidator.java:233: error: cannot find symbol
                TrustManagerImpl trustManager = (TrustManagerImpl) x509TrustManager;
                ^
  symbol:   class TrustManagerImpl
  location: class CertificateChainValidator
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/CertificateChainValidator.java:233: error: cannot find symbol
                TrustManagerImpl trustManager = (TrustManagerImpl) x509TrustManager;
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class TrustManagerImpl
  location: class CertificateChainValidator
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpsConnection.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            SSLClientSessionCache cache = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class SSLClientSessionCache
  location: class HttpsConnection
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpsConnection.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
                cache = FileClientSessionCache.usingDirectory(sessionDir);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable FileClientSessionCache
  location: class HttpsConnection
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpsConnection.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
            OpenSSLContextImpl sslContext = new OpenSSLContextImpl();
            ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLContextImpl
  location: class HttpsConnection
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpsConnection.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
            OpenSSLContextImpl sslContext = new OpenSSLContextImpl();
                                                ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLContextImpl
  location: class HttpsConnection
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java:379: error: cannot find symbol
                    X509Name x509Name = new X509Name(dName);
                    ^
  symbol:   class X509Name
  location: class SslCertificate.DName
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java:379: error: cannot find symbol
                    X509Name x509Name = new X509Name(dName);
                                            ^
  symbol:   class X509Name
  location: class SslCertificate.DName
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java:385: error: cannot find symbol
                        if (oid.elementAt(i).equals(X509Name.CN)) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable X509Name
  location: class SslCertificate.DName
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java:392: error: cannot find symbol
                        if (oid.elementAt(i).equals(X509Name.O)) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable X509Name
  location: class SslCertificate.DName
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java:399: error: cannot find symbol
                        if (oid.elementAt(i).equals(X509Name.OU)) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable X509Name
  location: class SslCertificate.DName
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:164: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
        if (installed instanceof com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache) {
                                                   ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:166: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
                    (com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache) installed);
                                       ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:185: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
        if (installed instanceof com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache) {
                                                   ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:186: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
            com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache installedCache =
                              ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:187: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
                    (com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache) installed;
                                       ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:199: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
        com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache responseCache =
                          ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java:200: error: package com.android.okhttp does not exist
                new com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache(directory, maxSize);
                                      ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/X509TrustManagerExtensions.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        if (tm instanceof TrustManagerImpl) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class TrustManagerImpl
  location: class X509TrustManagerExtensions
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/X509TrustManagerExtensions.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
            mDelegate = (TrustManagerImpl) tm;
                         ^
  symbol:   class TrustManagerImpl
  location: class X509TrustManagerExtensions
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
            PSKKeyManager.MAX_IDENTITY_HINT_LENGTH_BYTES;
            ^
  symbol:   variable PSKKeyManager
  location: class PskKeyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
    public static final int MAX_IDENTITY_LENGTH_BYTES = PSKKeyManager.MAX_IDENTITY_LENGTH_BYTES;
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable PSKKeyManager
  location: class PskKeyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    public static final int MAX_KEY_LENGTH_BYTES = PSKKeyManager.MAX_KEY_LENGTH_BYTES;
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable PSKKeyManager
  location: class PskKeyManager
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:136: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:150: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:167: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:184: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:202: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/PskKeyManager.java:220: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
            OpenSSLContextImpl sslContext = new OpenSSLContextImpl();
            ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLContextImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
            OpenSSLContextImpl sslContext = new OpenSSLContextImpl();
                                                ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLContextImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:419: error: cannot find symbol
        if (!(socket instanceof OpenSSLSocketImpl)) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:424: error: cannot find symbol
        return (OpenSSLSocketImpl) socket;
                ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:435: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(k, host, port, close);
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:435: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(k, host, port, close);
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:456: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket();
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:456: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket();
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:474: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:474: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(addr, port);
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(addr, port);
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:509: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:509: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:529: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(host, port);
        ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:529: error: cannot find symbol
        OpenSSLSocketImpl s = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) getDelegate().createSocket(host, port);
                               ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLSocketImpl
  location: class SSLCertificateSocketFactory
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLSessionCache.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        if (clientContext instanceof ClientSessionContext) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientSessionContext
  location: class SSLSessionCache
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLSessionCache.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            ((ClientSessionContext) clientContext).setPersistentCache(
              ^
  symbol:   class ClientSessionContext
  location: class SSLSessionCache
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLSessionCache.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
        mSessionCache = (SSLClientSessionCache) cache;
                         ^
  symbol:   class SSLClientSessionCache
  location: class SSLSessionCache
frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/SSLSessionCache.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
        mSessionCache = FileClientSessionCache.usingDirectory(dir);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable FileClientSessionCache
  location: class SSLSessionCache
  symbol:   variable OpenSSLEngine
  location: class AndroidKeyPairGenerator
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
        final X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
              ^
  symbol:   class X509V3CertificateGenerator
  location: class AndroidKeyPairGenerator
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
        final X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class X509V3CertificateGenerator
  location: class AndroidKeyPairGenerator
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
            case NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_RSA:
                 ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class AndroidKeyPairGenerator
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
            case NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_DSA:
                 ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class AndroidKeyPairGenerator
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
            return NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_RSA;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            return NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_DSA;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
            return NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_EC;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
        if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_DSA) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_EC) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_RSA) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:179: error: cannot find symbol
        if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_DSA) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:184: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_EC) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_RSA) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
        if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_DSA && spec != null) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (keyType == NativeCrypto.EVP_PKEY_RSA && spec != null) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable NativeCrypto
  location: class KeyPairGeneratorSpec
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        final OpenSSLEngine engine = OpenSSLEngine.getInstance("keystore");
              ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLEngine
  location: class AndroidKeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        final OpenSSLEngine engine = OpenSSLEngine.getInstance("keystore");
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable OpenSSLEngine
  location: class AndroidKeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:216: error: cannot find symbol
        if (key instanceof OpenSSLKeyHolder) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLKeyHolder
  location: class AndroidKeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
            pkeyAlias = ((OpenSSLKeyHolder) key).getOpenSSLKey().getAlias();
                          ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLKeyHolder
  location: class AndroidKeyStore
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
        PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(writer);
        ^
  symbol:   class PemWriter
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
        PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(writer);
                           ^
  symbol:   class PemWriter
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
            pw.writeObject(new PemObject("CERTIFICATE", o.getEncoded()));
                               ^
  symbol:   class PemObject
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
        PemReader pr = new PemReader(reader);
        ^
  symbol:   class PemReader
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
        PemReader pr = new PemReader(reader);
                           ^
  symbol:   class PemReader
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
        PemObject o;
        ^
  symbol:   class PemObject
  location: class Credentials
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:323: error: cannot find symbol
            final OpenSSLEngine engine = OpenSSLEngine.getInstance("keystore");
                  ^
  symbol:   class OpenSSLEngine
  location: class KeyChain
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:323: error: cannot find symbol
            final OpenSSLEngine engine = OpenSSLEngine.getInstance("keystore");
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable OpenSSLEngine
  location: class KeyChain
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:359: error: cannot find symbol
            TrustedCertificateStore store = new TrustedCertificateStore();
            ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class KeyChain
frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyChain.java:359: error: cannot find symbol
            TrustedCertificateStore store = new TrustedCertificateStore();
                                                ^
  symbol:   class TrustedCertificateStore
  location: class KeyChain
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
141 errors
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you cannot do it or it will require changes in your aosp.
It is much easy fix your libraries to build them with 1.7

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Yes you are right it requires many changes in the AOSP and im trying to fix them one by one i have to find 1.8 compatible modules and libraries to replace it in the aosp and i was able to fix the exception mentioned in the question mean while im trying to build the library for 1.7 aswell